# Maintain alternating row colors with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently using the jquery plugin tablesorter, found here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download

My problem is, when I create odd row coloring, and I click a table header to sort, my alternating colors are suddenly mixed up again because the sorter rearranged the rows. Is there a way I can keep my alternating row colors?

To see what my problem is, open this jsfiddle, and click one of the row headers.
http://jsfiddle.net/bJCKz/1/

Comment: You could use `tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: turquoise; }`  http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/HN3ys/  I'm trying to find a definitive source on it, but it looks as though it works with all current major browsers except versions of IE <= 8.
​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
.tablesorter tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: turquoise;   
}
```

Instead of classes. This way the rule is appied dynamically to odd rows.

**Updated demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/bJCKz/5/

Answer (score 5):

Don't add classes to your rows directly. Use CSS even / odd rules documented [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd).

Sample usage:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: But what if you only want this to apply to one GridView and leave other tables and gridviews alone?

Comment: What's stopping you from adding specific CSS class only to that particular GridView? `.myClass tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}`